# Directing output to stdout in a function without the calling code seeing it

Tags: function, powershell, stdout, powershell-2.0

I wrote several Powershell scripts which deploy software for a client. I used `Write-Host` to output a lot of information so that the progress of the deploy can be watched and they call this from one of their deploy application using `Start-Transcript` to capture this output.

However, they also need to be able to call some of these scripts from another application which can only capture output from stdout. This means that Write-Host won't work there since it outputs only to the console or host and doesn't get directed to stdout (correct?)

My thought was that I could change the code to use `Write-Out` instead, except that this causes another problem. Since I use functions and since functions in Powershell "return" **everything** that goes to stdout to the caller that would likely screw up any of my code that retrieves output from a function.

Is there a way to direct output to stdout from a function without it going to the calling code as the output of the function itself? Here is an example of the problem:

```
function Test-Output ([int]$number) {
    Write-Output "This is a string"
    return $number
}

[int]$someNumber = Test-Output 10

$someNumber
```

If you run the code above you'll see an error because Powershell is trying to assign "This is a string" to the integer `$someNumber`. If you change the variable to a `string` then it will capture the full output of the function (This is a string 10) and assign it to the variable.

Thanks for any suggestions that you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
function Add-Numbers {
    param (
        [double] $FirstNumber,
        [double] $SecondNumber
    )

    Write-Host "Hello World"

    return ($FirstNumber + $SecondNumber)
}

$result = Add-Numbers 1 2

#Write-Host "Result is $result"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. At a first glance I don't think that Tee-Object will do quite what I want, but I'll play around with it and see what I can get it to do. I had never heard of that cmdlet before.

The problem that I have though isn't a function failing. It's that throughout the course of a reusable function I might want to output information to the user on the progress. I can't figure out how to output that to stdout without it also going out as output from the function.

Comment: BTW, the current method that they are using is your last suggestion. We put everything out to a file using the `Start-Transcript` and then they have to scan that file. I thought that using stdout might be cleaner though.

Comment: I changed my answer. The only thing outputted to the stdout is "Hello World", the result of the function is stored in the variable $result.

Comment: You can test the above by saving as Test-Output.ps1 and run this.  powershell.exe -file Test-Output.ps1 2>&1> test.txt

Comment: Thanks! It looks like they are wrapping the call in multiple `start` and `cmd` calls (I have no idea why at the moment). The ultimate solution had to do with recrafting that call, but since your answer solves the actual question that I asked here I'm going to accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Function output and stdout are the same thing so the calling code is going to see anything output to the stdout stream.  In this case I would suggest using the `Write-Progress` cmdlet to report progress to the end user and leave actual function output alone.